# Интерфейс, как тип коллекции. Или как управлять коллекциями с разными типами?

Tags: c#, wpf, ооп, list, коллекции

Добрый день.
Имеется, к примеру, две модели:

```
public class ObjectOne : IObject
{
    public int PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public int PropertyTwo { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectTwo : IObject
{
    public int PropertyThree { get; set; }
    public int PropertyFour { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public interface IObject
{
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

И эти две модели исползуются, как тип в коллекции ObservableCollection

```
ObservableCollection<ObjectOne> ones = new ObservableCollection<ObjectOne>();
ObservableCollection<ObjectTwo> twos = new ObservableCollection<ObjectTwo>();
```

Мне необходимо, например, удалить элемент из коллекции, если IsSelected = false, но я не могу сделать как-нибудь одним кодом для двух этих коллекций. Передать таким образом образом не получается:

```
public static void Test(ObservableCollection<IObject> obj)
{

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ObservableCollection<ObjectOne> ones = new ObservableCollection<ObjectOne>();
   Test(ones);
}
```

Есть возможность передать вот так, но тогда я теряю ссылку на объект ones.

```
public static void Test(List<IObject> obj)
{

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ObservableCollection<ObjectOne> ones = new ObservableCollection<ObjectOne>();
   Test(ones.ToList<IObject>());
}
```

Как можно управлять этими двумя объектами с общими свойствами и при этом не потерять ссылку на объект?

Comment: Перенести IsSelected на IObject и определить ObservableCollection<IObject>

Comment: @AK: `ObservableCollection<IObject>` хуже, потому что туда можно добавить как `ObjectOne`, так и `ObjectTwo`, а у автора однородные коллекции.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, так:

```
public static void Test<T>(ObservableCollection<T> obj) where T : IObject
{
    ...
}
```

Возможно, вам понадобятся другие generic-ограничения.

Comment: спасибо большое. Это то, что нужно!

Comment: @SeriousDown: Пожалуйста!